# In Jest and Sinon.JS, server.requests[0] doesn't seem to be a promise? But Promise.all(server.requests) seems to work

Tags: jestjs, sinon

I am checking into how [Sinon.JS](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/fake-xhr-and-server/) works:

It seems that if we do

```
const requests = [];

let getDataThunk = actions.getData();
requests.push(store.dispatch(getDataThunk));
```

then `requests[0]` is a promise, and we can do `requests[0].then()`.

However, with

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
```

then `server.requests[0]` is not a promise, and `server.requests[0].then()` does not work.  However, I found that `Promise.all(server.requests).then()` seem to work well waiting for all requests to finish.  How does this work?

Comment: have never worked with sinon so maybe I'm wrong. Docs says [fakeServer.requests](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/fake-xhr-and-server/#array-serverrequests) is array of  `FakeXMLHttpRequest` and it does not look like Promise in any way. As for `Promise.all` it does not require list to contain only Promises. It works with any sync value as well: `Promise.all([1,2, 'a', window])`. Putting this as a comment 'cause not sure if I've got your question correct.

Comment: yes... if you do `Promise.all([a,b,c])` and `a,b,c` are not promises, then won't it resolve right away?  I was thinking what if they are not promises but some of them is a "thenable", but the fact that you can't do `a.then()` means that it is not a "thenable".

Comment: they are resolved right away but `Promise.all([...]).then()` part will be anyway called in async way even if there is no single then'able in the list

Comment: hm... so perhaps it worked due to the fact that it was done in the next event cycle... interesting... so maybe this is one way to make it work... we then, can also use `setTimeout(fn, 0)` to make it work too in that case. It is an interesting way to make it work, because it is like "instead of letting you wait 2 or 3 seconds for the data to come back, you are mocking up the network response anyway, so it is instantaneous, so the next event cycle is all it takes to guarantee the data came back."